# How to make summarise react dynamically to shiny user's input?

Tags: r, shiny, tidyr

I am building a shiny app which requires some data manipulation prior to display a chart.
My app works nice when I 'hard code' the parameter in the **summarise** function, from **tidyr package**. However it does not work when I make it dynamic, using the **reactive()** feature.

below is my example, do you know how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance for your help and best regards!

**This works**

```
  selectedAAA <- reactive({
                 dplot <- mydata %>% 
                    filter(V1 %in% input$aaa, V2 %in% input$bbb) %>% 
                    group_by(date, V1, V2)
                 dplot <-  dplot %>% 
                   summarise(LT = mean(var, na.rm = TRUE))  %>% # here 'var' is the name of one variable in mydata dataset. Works if hardcoded
                   spread(Material_Type, LT)
                 rownames(dplot) <- dplot$date 
                dplot <- select(dplot, -c(V1, date))
                dplot[is.na(dplot)] <- 0
                dplot <- as.data.frame(dplot)
                })
```

**This does not work**

```
   # reactive feature to make the graph interactive, based on user's input (selectInput whose id is 'LT')

   selectedLT <- reactive({
                  switch(input$LT,
                  "Label 1" = var1,
                  "Label 2" = var2)
                  })


  selectedAAA <- reactive({
                 dplot <- mydata %>% 
                    filter(V1 %in% input$aaa, V2 %in% input$bbb) %>% 
                    group_by(date, V1, V2)
                 dplot <-  dplot %>% 
                   summarise(LT = mean(selectedLT(), na.rm = TRUE))  %>% # here selectedLT() is the user's selected variable in mydata dataset. Does not work
                   spread(Material_Type, LT)
                 rownames(dplot) <- dplot$date 
                dplot <- select(dplot, -c(V1, date))
                dplot[is.na(dplot)] <- 0
                dplot <- as.data.frame(dplot)
                })
```

I have the following error message:

```
 Warning in mean.default(selectedLT(), na.rm = TRUE) :
   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I believe `summarise` is actually from `dplyr`.  Second, I think you could try passing strings instead of the actual variable.  Try the following with the `summarise_` function instead.

```
  selectedLT <- reactive({
                  switch(input$LT,
                  "Label 1" = "var1",
                  "Label 2" = "var2")
                  })


  selectedAAA <- reactive({
                 dplot <- mydata %>% 
                    filter(V1 %in% input$aaa, V2 %in% input$bbb) %>% 
                    group_by(date, V1, V2)
                 dplot <-  dplot %>% 
                   summarise_(LT = mean(selectedLT(), na.rm = TRUE))  %>% # here selectedLT() is the user's selected variable in mydata dataset. Does not work
                   spread(Material_Type, LT)
                 rownames(dplot) <- dplot$date 
                dplot <- select(dplot, -c(V1, date))
                dplot[is.na(dplot)] <- 0
                dplot <- as.data.frame(dplot)
                })
```